# Unable to preload multiple-hierarchy model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a 3-level hierarchy model relationship, that is, `model1` belongs to `model2` and `model2` belongs to `model3`.

I'm trying to preload `model2` and `model3` for the `model1`:

```
  my_models = Repo.all(Model1)
    |> Enum.map(fn (x) ->
      Repo.preload(x, :model2)
    end) 
    |> Enum.map(fn(x) -> # error "no function clause matching in Ecto.Repo.Preloader.preload/4"
      Repo.preload(x.model2, :model3)
    end)
```

The error is "**no function clause matching in Ecto.Repo.Preloader.preload/4**"

Comment: Why are you preloading in `Enum.map`? That defeats the whole purpose of preloading. Why not `Repo.all(Model1) |> Repo.preload(model2: [:model3])`?

Comment: @Dogbert, doesn't preloading work only on a single entity?

Comment: Nope, works on lists as well and also supports loading nested associations efficiently.

Comment: @Dogbert, that doesn't work, they're not getting preloaded. is it because it's going from "belongs to" and not "has_many" like the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
my_models = Repo.all(Model1) |> Repo.preload(model2: :model3)
```

Notice that this is not the same as:

```
my_models = Repo.all(Model1) |> Repo.preload([:model2, :model3])
```

As explained in https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3

If you can provide more of the error message, I'll be able to explain why you are getting that error message. It is likely that model2 (in the 2nd `Enum.map`) is `nil`, and https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/66e90c97054cd855c7cbb694bc79a0b9313f119b/lib/ecto/repo/preloader.ex#L36 only works with a `map` or a `list`.

Using the nested preload as above will handle this case for you.

Comment: that doesn't work, they're not getting preloaded. is it because it's going from "belongs to" and not "has_many" like the documentation?

Comment: This should definitely work with both. Please could you provide your post your schema and the result of running `Repo.preload(model1, model2: :model3)` in your question to help identify the issue?

Comment: the :model3 isn't getting loaded, should I have Model3 -> Model1  "has_many through" in  or anything like that?

Comment: @Joshimari How are you attempting to access model3?

Comment: model1_item.model2.model3.id

Comment: Is `model2` preloaded? What is the value of `model2.model3` and `model2.model3_id`?

Comment: .yes. `Ecto.Association.NotLoaded`. but `model2.model3_id` has been loaded as it should because "___external_id" is getting loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
Repo.preload([{:model2, :model3}])
```

Should do the trick. You can nest this structure however deep you want. E.g. 5 models deep:

```
Repo.preload([
  {:model1, [
    {:model2, [
      {:model3, [
        {:model4, :model5}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
])
```

Comment: the model2 is getting loaded, model3 isn't

Comment: For reference `[{:model2, :model3}]` is exactly the same as `[model2: :model3]` http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists

Answer (score 0):

```
Repo.all(from m in Model1, preload: [model2: :model3])
```

Good article - [nested preload in ecto](https://tkowal.wordpress.com/2016/04/23/nested-preload-in-ecto/)